# PHP: getting multiple checkboxes with different names/id's with php

Tags: checkbox

I was trying and trying for four hours to get a value of checkbox with a different name and I really hope you guys can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance. Here is my problem:

I have a form with some questions and alternatives to chose which ever questions have their own id and every alternative that also has its own id and of course every alternative also has a question id that belongs to the question. I have one table for questions and another table for alternatives.
For example:
1) Chose some equation to get 20. (Let's say this question gets question_id=1)
A) 5*4   (Let's say this one gets alternative_id = 10)
B) 6*5   (alternative_id = 20)
C) 100/5 (alternative_id = 30)
D) 4*5   (and let's say this one gets alternative_id = 40)
Off course all of those above will have question_id=1

2) What's a synonym of handsome? (Let's say this question gets question_id=2)
A) Ugly              (Let's say this one gets alternative_id = 40)
B) Fine-looking      (alternative_id = 60)
C) Good-looking      (alternative_id = 7)
 
D) Kind              (alternative_id = 5)

Off course all of those above will have question_id=2

Now my question is how to get those alternative-id value with their questions-id's?

Let's choose from question Nummber 1 => A, C, and D (which means id 10, 30, 40)
and from question number 2 => B and C (which means id, 60,7).
I want to get those value when I click on submit button and here this what I am doing.

If I use this in my checkbox form

```
print '<input type="checkbox" name="alternative['.$row_q['question_id'].']" value="'.$row['alternative_id'].'">'.$row['alternative'].'</input>';
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" />
```

And when I submit I use this code:

```
$alt = $_GET['alternative'];
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])&& $_REQUEST['submit'] != "")  { 
 if(isset($_GET['alternative'])&& $_GET['alternative'] != ''){ 
foreach($alt AS $key=>$alt3){
    echo $key."-".$alt3."<br>";

}
```

}

```
}
```

What I am getting is the last chosen alternative of every question. In this case 40 and 7 with keys (question_id's),
which means 40 is the id of alternative D in question 1 and 7 is the id of alternative C in question number 2.

If I use the name of checkbox without an index like this:

```
print '<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[]" value="'.$row['alternative_id'].'">'.$row['alternative'].'</input>';
```

then I get all the chosen id's together like a bunch BUT without key's (with out question_id).
I mean all together for question number 1 and number 2 like this:
10
30
40
60
7
And it's difficult to know , to sort and to insert which id's belong to which question. I feel like I have to loop arrays within arrays but I really don't how to do it.
How can I get the value of the chosen alternatives for every part of the question? Thank you again for your help in advance and I hope you guys understand what I mean.

======================

`$alt` is a value of chosen alternatives ID. I get them from
`$_GET['alternative'];` and [alternative] is the name of checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative['.$row_q['question_id'].']" value="'.$row['alternative_id'].'">'.$row['alternative'].'</input>
```

So I get the value by writing

```
$alt = $_GET['alternative']; in another page.<br>
```

The problem is:

For example if I chose A, B, C from question 1 and B , C from question 2
Then I get `print_r` like this:
`Array ( [1] => 40 [2] => 7 )` , you see I get only C, `[1] => 40` from question #1 with it’s question id as a key, which is the last one from question #1. I don’t get A and B Only C from question nr 1. I mean [1] is question id and =>40 is alternative_id But the last one of chosen alternatives of question #1.
and I get C `[2] => 7`  from question #2 which is the last chosen of question #2 with it’s question id.

My target is like this:
I have a column in my question table with name alt_id.
My table of questions  look like this:
`Q_id`, `question`, `alt_id`

Let’s question nr you chose A, B and C witch alternative id’s is 10, 30, 40
Now I want collect them with comma with implode() and write them as 10,30,40 and put them in column alt_id in row of question id nr 1

```
Q_id       question                                            alt_id
1          Chose some equation to get 20                       10,30,40
2          What's a synonym of handsome?                       60,7
3          .................................................   89,6,50,30
```

I want them like this

```
ARRAY([1]=>10,30,40  [2]=>60,7  [3]=>89,6,50,30)
```

Then I want to update question table like this (Of course `alt_id` is NULL from the beginning)

```
    foreach($alt AS $key=>$alternativ){
    $query = 'UPDATE question SET alt_id = '.alternative.'  WHERE q_id  = '.$key.' ';
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    }
```

So my problem is how can I get them like this `ARRAY([1]=>10,30,40  [2]=>60,7  [3]=>89,6,50,30 and so on….`

==============Second uppdating: ========== 
To gererait thos value from my database I use this script: (I will show you sourge page too):

```
$sql_q = " SELECT * FROM questions WHERE title_id = ".$title_id." "; 
$res_q= mysql_query($sql_q); 
while($row_q = mysql_fetch_array($res_q)){ 
    $q_id = $row_q['q_id']; 
    $sql_a = " SELECT alt_id, alt, q_id FROM ice_alternative WHERE q_id = ".$q_id." "; 
    $res_a = mysql_query($sql_a); 
    while ($row_a = mysql_fetch_array($res_a)){ 
        $alt_id = $row_a['alt_id']; ?> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="alternative[<?=$row_q['q_id']?>]" value="<?=$row_a['alt_id']?>"/><?=$row_a['alt']?></input><br /><br />
        <?php 
        } 
        }
```

And When I see the sourge page it's shows me like this:

```
<form action="st_q2.php" name="reply2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

1) Chose some equation to get 20

<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1]" value="10"/>5*4</input><br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1]" value="20"/>6*5</input><br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1]" value="30"/>100/5</input><br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1]" value="40"/> 4*5</input><br /><br />
<hr /><br><br><br>

2 ) What's a synonym of handsome?<br><br>    

<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2]" value="50"/>Ugly</input><br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2]" value="60"/>Fine-looking</input><br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2]" value="7"/>Good-looking</input><br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2]" value="5"/>Kind</input><br /><br />
<hr />      
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" />
  </form>
```

Then in my next page (st_q2.php) I wrote my code like this:

```
$alt = $_POST['alternative'];
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])&& $_REQUEST['submit'] != "")  { 
if(isset($_POST['alternative'])&& $_POST['alternative'] != ''){ 
foreach($alt AS $key=>$alternativ){
    $query = 'UPDATE question SET alt_id = '.alternative.'  WHERE q_id  = '.$key.' ';
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    }
```

=================  Forth Edition ============ 
if I give name all my fields for question 1 as you said: `name="alternative[1][]"`
then I get

```
1) Chose some equation to get 20

<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="10"/>5*4</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="20"/>6*5</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="30"/>100/5</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="40"/> 4*5</input>  
<hr /><br><br><br>

2 ) What's a synonym of handsome?<br><br>    

<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="50"/>Ugly</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="60"/>Fine-looking</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="7"/>Good-looking</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="5"/>Kind</input> 
<hr />      
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" />
  </form>
```

if I give name all my fields for `name="alternative[<?=$row_q['q_id']?>][]"`
then I get

```
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="10"/>5*4</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="20"/>6*5</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="30"/>100/5</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][]" value="40"/> 4*5</input>  
<hr /><br><br><br>

2 ) What's a synonym of handsome?<br><br>    

<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2][]" value="50"/>Ugly</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2][]" value="60"/>Fine-looking</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2][]" value="7"/>Good-looking</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2][]" value="5"/>Kind</input>
```

if I give name all my fields for `name="alternative[<?=$row_q['q_id']?>][<?=$row_a['alt_id']?>]"`
then I get

```
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][10]" value="10"/>5*4</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][20]" value="20"/>6*5</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][30]" value="30"/>100/5</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[1][40]" value="40"/> 4*5</input>  
<hr /><br><br><br>

2 ) What's a synonym of handsome?<br><br>    

<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2][50]" value="50"/>Ugly</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2][60]" value="60"/>Fine-looking</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2][7]" value="7"/>Good-looking</input> 
<input type="checkbox" name="alternative[2][5]" value="5"/>Kind</input>
```

But stil I can't get them as `ARRAY([1]=>10,30,40  [2]=>60,7  [3]=>89,6,50,30)`
even if I run SELECTION inside `foreach loop with implode(','$_POST['alternative'])`
What I want is to update column alt_id in question table. From the begining is question table like this:
   Q_id        question                                                                                    alt_id
    1          Chose some equation to get 20                                       Null
    2          What's a synonym of handsome?                  Null
 3          .................................................               Null

But then after uppdating I want it will look like this following:

Q_id        question                                                                                    alt_id
    1          Chose some equation to get 20                                       10,30,40
    2          What's a synonym of handsome?                                       60,7
 3          .................................................                   89,6,50,30

Comment: What's $alt2 ? Where is it set?

Comment: Thank you Octern, I mean $alt not $alt2. But stile the same problem.

Comment: What are the exact contents of $alt? Please show it using print_r().

Comment: I tried to add comment and wrote my code in this "Add comment" but the text was not nice writing so I have already added for you as a  new question with title "PHP Value of checkboxes". Please have a look on that and I have explained well and the text look like good. Thank you again Octern.

Comment: Don't add a new question, just use the "edit" link that appears beneath this question.

Comment: Ok, now I have added more information about my problem , I just added them after this line: =====

Comment: On the page where you input alternatives, what are the names of the fields? Not the PHP code that generates them, but the actual names you see if you view source on that page. It sounds like they might have conflicting names, causing you to only get the last of the alternatives.

Comment: I have edited with source page, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all your alternative fields for a given question have the same name, so only the last one is getting passed to the next page. To use array notation properly, name all your fields for question 1 `<input type="text" name="alternative[1][]">`. Then in your `$_POST` array on the next page, `alternative` will be an array where element `1` is an array containing each of the options you submitted for question 1.

Then you'll iterate over $_POST['alternative'] with something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['alternative'] as $qid => $question) {
    foreach($question as $altnum => $alternative) {
        // deal with alternatives here
        // using $qid for question ID and $altnum for alternative number
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited it about 18 hours ago but when you say <input type="text" name="alternative[1][]"> do you mean checkbox , right? Not type as text. Because I don't have text fields When I gate them from my database , I get them in checkbox'es.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. I was thinking about the code you use to input options when you're writing the questions, not about how the user selects options. I don't think I can help you with this; it's too complicated and I don't have that much time to spend on it. I think you'll need to do some more debugging and try to pinpoint the source of the error.

Comment: I agree, it's easy with radio buttons becouse you have only one alternative to chose from every question. But I will solve this problem by inserting to another new table by giving every chosen alternative inserting to this new table with id's and get the same q_id to those chosen alternatives. I can make it in that way, I just wanted them as an array but as you see it's difficult. What I want to say now is "Thank you very very and very much for your time."  I can't stop to thank you.